# How to use nginx to get the post request content，the data enctype is multipart/form-data

Tags: jsp, nginx, lua

I want to use nginx to get the post request content,the data enctype is multipart/form-data. I used the following config,nginx config:

```
 upstream syy{
     server 201.23.xx.xx;
    }


server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  localhost;



lua_need_request_body on;

    location /test {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass http://syy;
    proxy_buffering off;
    lua_code_cache off;
    content_by_lua_file /usr/local/openresty/luasrc/att.lua;
    }
```

lua file:

```
function writefile(filename,info)
local file = assert(io.open(filename,"ab"))
file:write(info)
file:close()
end

ngx.req.read_body()
local value = "/home/tmp/"..os.date("%Y%m%d%H")..".att"
local data = ngx.req.get_post_args()
if data ~= nil then
    if type(data) == "table" then
        writefile(value,table.concat(data,",").."\n")
    else
        writefile(value,data.."\n")
    end
end
```

But when i access the test website, I only got a empty file， like this login.jsp, which is a empty file. and the browser tip me to download login.jsp.

Thx very much！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all "proxy_pass" and "content_by_lua_file" are not supposed to be used together. You either use proxy_pass or content_by_lua. This is why the browser is trying to download the file rather than actually executing it.

Not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve but you might wanna use "rewrite_by_lua_file" instead of "content_by_lua_file". At this stage you can do some manipulation before you reverse proxy your request. You can also use "access_by_lua*" for the snippet you use but it all depends what nginx functionality you want to use.

```
rewrite_by_lua_file /usr/local/openresty/luasrc/att.lua;
```

Comment: thx very much,"access_by_lua" is work. I want to record the attachment dataflow, which users upload to the web application and used apached commons-fileupload component.

Comment: @Cüneyt Aliustaoğlu could you please have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72408894/nginx-removes-contents-from-multipart-formdata